# Sudden change in matplotlib visualization

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am using **`Python 2.7.6`** with **`Ipython 1.2.1`** and **`matplotlib 1.3.1`** in Ubuntu 14.04.

```
In [4]: print(sys.version)
2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2]

In [5]: matplotlib.__version__
Out[5]: '1.3.1'
```

All of a sudden, **without any update to matplotlib or Python,** the visualization of the matplotlib plot changed.

**The old classical plot of matplotlib looked like this**: [image]

**Now the new plot always seems to look this way:**

[image]

As you can clearly see, now **I am missing axis lines, legend border, errorbar caplines.** I am using the same python code and the same interpretor!

Has this happened to anyone, or is there a solution to this?

Comment: That's definitely a bug somewhere ... The new matplotlib still shows the axis spines by default. I know that because I usually remove the top and right one explicitly for better aesthetics :P

Comment: Take a look at your `rcparam` and compare it to a default installation to see if you have accidentally changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a small bug with matplotlib.

I found out that because I was using both `seaborn` (which uses matplotlib to plot graphs) and `matplotlib` to plot graphs at the same time in the same piece of code, I was getting the error. Once I separated the codes, it was back to normal.

If there is someone who uses both `seaborn` and `matplotlib` experience this error, do report!

Comment: Hi, I've noticed that several tag wiki edits you have suggested copy a significant amount of content from an external source. Generic descriptions such as encyclopedia articles and ad copy do not provide useful guidance; try creating something [useful to this community *specifically*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/), and be sure to attribute the original author. See: [How to reference material written by others](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). Thanks!

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I was not aware of it. I shall edit some of the tag's which I took from Wikipedia. Is it enough if I mention wikipedia?

Comment: That is *technically* enough, though I would recommend trying to reword the pages so that they are easier to read and that any unnecessary information for Stack Overflow is removed.

Answer (score -1):

There are different backends [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html) can use. I could imagine you installed a new driver for your graphic card or whatever and there is a automatic detection in matplotlib like "is opengl available".

However, you are able to change the backend and you could give it a try.

[Also read this Stack Overflow thread about list of backends.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091993/list-of-all-available-matplotlib-backends)

Comment: How do you know which one to use? My current backend is `"TkAgg"`

Comment: Thats a good question. http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend gives a small overview with the usage of the backend. I would first just try something different and have a look if it solves the issues. Afterwards I would start thinking about which one fits my needs (do I need vector graphics or something else?).