# Matplotlib didn’t show the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I don’t know why my matplotlib didn’t show plots, and no errors too. I thinks I missing something on its installation because when in IPython notebooks an QtIpython using `%mayplotlib inline` directive have no problems but when running from terminal or script didn’t show anything. Any ideas ??

for example, in QtIPython and Ipython notebook I run

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
ax.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,11], '-r')
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

and the plot shows Ok!

but in a simple script with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
ax.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,11], '-r')
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

didn’t show anything

Comment: @unutbu its not releate, I, going to edit my post with example code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use matplotlib inline in IPython notebook, the plots are shown automatically. If you plot things in a script you have to put a `plt.show()` at the end to actually show the figure. In the terminal you can also use `plt.ion()` to switch on intreactive mode.

Comment: I, know, but the figure did not appear, and in the terminal needier, so maybe is something with the figure window

Comment: Then it may be a problem with the backend. Have you tried different ones? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091993/list-of-all-available-matplotlib-backends) shows you how to find out your options, and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285193/how-to-switch-backends-in-matplotlib-python) it is described how to change it. Maybe you have to try a few.

Comment: I'm running the script in my computer and that exact code works, I'm getting a plot with a (ugly) red line with grid on. Python 2.7 @ Windows 8.1.

Comment: Thanks!!!  it was a backend problem, who can I setup the default backend? it always start with 'agg'

Comment: There should be a text file with the default rcParams somewhere. The details depend on your OS.

Comment: @efirvida: The backend can be set in [the matplotlibrc file](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html).