# import matplotlib.pyplot crashes on jupyter notebook

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I have a jupyter notebook running on a remote cluster to which I have set up an ssh tunnel. Everything was working fine till today. Now everytime I do :

```
import matplotlib # This works
%matplotlib inline # This causes kernel to restart
import matplotlib.pyplot # This also causes the kernel to restart
```

Running a standalone ipython interpreter and doing :

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot ## Leads to Core dumped : Segementation Fault
```

Running the same on a python interpreter works fine.

Jupyter version : 4.1.1
Python version : 2.7.7

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Often, this kind of error seems to be related to the backend. Have you tried any other backends? Do these result in the same error? Like this we could narrow down the source of the error.
(I don't have a remote cluster, so I can not reproduce it.)

You can find available backends as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091993/list-of-all-available-matplotlib-backends).

Answer (score 0):

I perhaps have the same problem but on my local machine.  I got into jupyter3-qtconsole 4.2.1 with Python 3.4.5 and IPython 5.0.0. and enter 
`%matplotlib

> Using matplotlib backend: Qt4Agg`
>   the error message (shortened):

```
File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 603, in _run_callback
ret = callback()
```

and finally

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import NoOpContext as context
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'NoOpContext'

Same thing happens in a notebook but in a straightforward IPython terminal, everything runs OK
Hope this is helpful to someone