# How To Get Rid Of "Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)" in Pychar+Django

Tags: django, pycharm

When I run my test suite using pycharm for a django app in my local machine, at certain test I got:

`Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)`

If I run that test in isolation using pycharm, it succeeds, which means there's not a problem in the app or test. If I disable that particular test, down the line I get the same error, in a different test, this one a dummy test! This seems to indicate that it's a problem with pycharm itself. **The full test suite succeeds in the CI environment**.

I tried some suggestion from other stackoverflow questions, which didn't solve the issue:

- [Unticking the Qt box in PyCharm Settings (Build, Ex... -> Python Debugger)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40203572/pycharm-debug-segmentation-fault-signal-11)
- [Uninstalling python3-pyqt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40203572/pycharm-debug-segmentation-fault-signal-11) (same link as above): Pyqt is not installed in my local machine.
- [Ticking gevent compatible in Pycharm Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016449/pycharm-debugger-instantly-exits-with-139-code)

My Environment: python 3.7.3, djando 2.2.8, Pycharm 2019.2.4 (professional edition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solve it. [This entry](https://bugs.python.org/issue34355) gave me the clue. It wasn't a pycharm issue, but a bug in python itself. I discovered when running flake8 itself failed.

I was using python 3.7.3 in ubuntu, which seems to have have SIGSEGV Error (Address boundary error). After upgrading to python 3.7.5, the issue was fixed.