# What GUI library is matplotlib using?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, matplotlib

By the appearance of `matplotlib`, I guess it is using PyQt; but when I looked into the code of it, I didn't find it importing any GUI library at all. So, what exactly does `matplotlib` use to show the graph (for example, the window when calling `plt.show()`)?

Comment: I believe matplotlib supports a large number of backends - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091993/list-of-all-available-matplotlib-backends

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can tell which backend matplotlib is using with the `get_backend()` method:

```
matplotlib.get_backend()
```

You can see a list of all available backends with `rcsetup.all_backends`:

```
matplotlib.rcsetup.all_backends
```